# Loop through list of values in Oracle query results

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, foreach, nested

In Oracle, is it possible to loop through values that are returned from a query and use those in a nested query?

For example:

```
For each A 
In Table1 
Where B = C 
(Select D 
From Table2 
Where D = A)
Loop
End;
```

Comment: Yes.  Do some research on cursors.

Comment: That would require using a cursor. You should be able to find an example by searching here. Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, there may be a better way to accomplish it, though.

Comment: @KenWhite I am trying to build a list of unique values (A) based on one criteria (where columnB = C) then execute two nested queries to pull the first row of data  from a variety of tables based on each of the values (A) pulled in the first query. Not sure if that makes sense. Ultimately, I am trying to use a loop rather than execute the same query for each unique (A) value. This will all be executed in excel using ADODB.

Answer (score 1):

Just use SQL:

```sql
SELECT D 
FROM   Table2 
WHERE  D IN ( SELECT A FROM Table1 WHERE B = C )
```

Or you can use collections:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER(10,0);
```

then:

```sql
DECLARE
  a_array int_list;
  d_array int_list;
BEGIN
  SELECT a
  BULK COLLECT INTO a_array
  FROM   table1
  WHERE  b = c;

  SELECT d
  BULK COLLECT INTO d_array
  FROM   Table2
  WHERE  d MEMBER OF a_array;

  FOR i IN 1 .. d_array.COUNT LOOP
    NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop using PL/SQL to accomplish your goal. The general syntax follows. Replace `NULL;` with whatever logic you wish in the inner for loop.

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT a 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE b = c)
  LOOP
    FOR s IN (
      SELECT d
      FROM table2
      WHERE d = a)
    LOOP
      NULL;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```